# What regex (if any) could be used to remove query strings in WordPress?

Tags: regex, wordpress, url

On my WordPress site, with Google and Facebook adding query strings like ?GCLID=34o8u343 or ?FBCLID=2o38u3ljlkj, it breaks my redirects. Like:

Old Url: website.com/old-url
Redirects to New Url: website.com/new-url

When Facebook sends someone over, it's website/old-url?fbclid=9283u4938u4 or whatever.

Is there regex that can simply strip off everything starting with ? so the redirects continue to work?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score -1):

As the query string starts from the first question mark in the URL, you can use the following:

`^(.*?)\?.*$`

`^` start of the line
`(.*?)` group containing all characters (lazy-expansion)
`\?` up to the first question mark
`.*` any characters
`$` end of the line

You can see it in action on regex101.com [here](https://regex101.com/r/xie3E5/1) with the URL you provided.

Comment: Excellent. How would I throw this in a regex redirect in WordPress? As in:

Regular Expression = ?
and 
URL = ?

Comment: You asked for the regex, you got the regex. I don't know how to apply them in WordPress, sorry.